# SQL query to include V and E props in the result

Tags: orientdb, orientdb2.2

I feel like this should be simple, but lots of searching and experimenting has not produced any results.

I have a very simple ODB database with one V and one E class. V has various props and E has one prop: "order"

This simple ODB SQL query...

```
select expand(out()) from #12:34
```

...returns all the props from the V records connected by the "out" edges on #12:34 (i.e. the child records of #12:34), working as expected.

But what I'm not able to do is to also include the one prop from those edges, as well as sort by that E prop (which should be trivial once I can get it into the projections).

Answer (score 0):

This works fine in OrientDB v 3.0.0RC2 (the GA will be released in a few days)

```
MATCH
  {class:V, where:(@rid = ?), as:aVertex}.outE(){as:theEdge}.inV(){as:otherVertex}
RETURN theEdge:{*}, otherVertex:{*}
```

you can also return single properties with

```
RETURN theEdge.prop1 as p1, theEdge.prop2 as p2, otherVertex.propX as p3
```

Comment: Very nice. On 2.2, it looks like the :{*} syntax isn't supported. Is that right?

Comment: By the way, is there even a way to do this without using MATCH?

Comment: Where the heck is the :{*} syntax documented? I can't find it anywhere.

Comment: Here it is ;-) https://orientdb.com/docs/3.0.x/sql/SQL-Projections.html#nested-projections

Comment: and yes, it's supported only on v 3.0